# Confusion about { length: } provided below

Tags: javascript

Using React (JSX) programming and I've encountered the following code :

`range: (min, max) => Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => min + i)`

I wanna know what does length : `{ length: max - min + 1 }` and underscore : `(_, i) => min + i)` does and returns.

I have tried reading the docs for Array.from and still doesn't understand what the length and underscore means.

Are there any pages where I can learn those two `length` and `_`?

Thanks!

Comment: underscore is often used to mark unused parameters. It is an identifier for the first parameter, just never used.

Comment: It should create a sequential array from min to max. [min, min+1, min+2, ..., max-1, max]

Comment: Which docs did you read? [MDN ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) explain this quite ok: ["Array.from() lets you create Arrays from:

    array-like objects (**objects with a `length` property**..." ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Description) and [
// the value of `v` below will be `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from)

Comment: You can read this document. https://2ality.com/2014/05/es6-array-methods.html

Comment: I finally understand how it works. Thank you for supporting me on my journey to React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is a good explanation of [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). From the docs, we can see that Array.from takes 1-3 arguments.

> Array.from(arrayLike[, mapFn[, thisArg]])

With **one** argument, it tries to turn whatever was passed as the argument into an array. So:
`Array.from("foo")` become `["f", "o", "o"]`. Cool!

With **two** arguments, `Array.from` uses the second argument as a function and tries to apply it to each element of the array that was created from the first argument.

So if you had `Array.from("foo", el => el.toUpperCase());` it would turn the string "foo" into `["f", "o", "o"]` and then run the function `el => el.toUpperCase()` on each letter and you would end up with `["F", "O", "O"]`. Neat!

You have this:

`Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => min + i)`

It's similar to our `Foo` example. The first argument becomes an array and the second argument is a function that gets applied to each element of the new array.

This is just like [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)!

So, first, let's figure out what happens if we do Array.from with an object: `Array.from({ length: 3 })`. Wow! We get `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

For each element, it runs the function given in the second argument: `(_, i) => min + i)`. Looking at the *map* documentation we can see

> arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])

so that `_` is a variable that holds the current value of the element in the array. The value in each element is `undefined` which is why they used an underscore. They don't care about the value. What they **do** care about is the index. And that is the second argument to the map function.

Let's try it: `Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => i)` gives us `[0, 1, 2]`. Awesome! So it takes the object, makes an array from it, then uses that to map the index of each element to a new array.

Still, there's some min/max stuff in there. I think you can see where this is going.

They wrap the cool function in another function an pass in the min (the start value) and the max (the end value). Then they create an array of undefined values of that length. THEN fill the array with the indexes adjusted from the minimum. So `range(5, 10)` probably gives us `[5...10]`. Let's try it.

`const range = (min, max) => Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => min + i);` gives us `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. Sweet!

Now, you had `range: (min, max) => ...` not `const range = (min, max) => ...`. That is probably because your range is a method of an object. There is probably some code somewhere that says `const somelibrary = { range: (min, max) => Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => min + i)}` or something similar. And to call the range method, you need to do `somelibrary.range(5, 10)`. But the result is the same.

You end up with an array filled with values starting at `min` and ending at `max`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have learned a lot from what you've described. I will try to study and learn more about syntax and how each functions work.